# Yatzy, using asciitable, how to fix the columns?

Tags: python

My issue right now with yatzy is that I wanna print a board with columns containing names and how much points they have. Currently my code is looking like this:

```
from terminaltables import AsciiTable

class Player:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.lista={"ones":0,"twos":0,"threes":0, "fours":0,"fives":0,"sixs":0,"abovesum":0,"bonus":0,"onepair":0,"twopair":0,"threepair":0,"fourpair":0,"smalladder":0,"bigladder":0,"house":0,"chance":0,"yatzy":0,"totalsum":0}
        self.spelarlista=[]

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def welcome(self):
        t=0
        print("Welcome to the yahtzee game!")
        players = int(input("How many players: "))
        rounds=0
        while not players==rounds:
            player=input("What is your name?: ")
            rounds=rounds+1
            self.spelarlista.append(Player(player))
        table_data = [
            ['Heading1', 'Heading2'],
            ['hans', 'joha'],
            ['jens', 'drev'],
            ['sonny', 'elias']]
        table = AsciiTable(table_data)
        print(table.table)


def main():
    play=Player("joakim")
    play.welcome()

main()
```

Notice that the asciitable code is pretty much copied, because I'm not sure how to solve the issue to get columns based on how many players I have. As you can see, it starts with asking how many players, let's say I go with 3, "James","Patrik" and "Andy", then I want 3 columns, is this possible to make? Second question, is Asciitable the right way to go? Is there an easier way, perhaps with something built-in already in python, I just tried this out because I got recommended. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe I can print the first colum, and then have a for-loop and put the following columns next to each other, not sure how to implement this tho

Comment: So I think i've fixed how to add the right amount of columns up there, but I still cant figure how to implement so that I will get the right amount of points on each player, is it possible to make every row in asciitable a headingsrow?